# Restoring GRUB2 on Software RAID 0 using LiveCD after Windows 7 wiped it

Tags: 10.10, grub2, live-cd, raid, bootloader

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my system. However, I need to install Windows 7 back, and I expect that it would alter GRUB and it did.

Right now, my partition on my **Software RAID 0** looks like this:

[image]

nvidia_acajefec1 is Ubuntu 10.10 and nvidia_acajefec3 is Windows 7.

I've been following some guides around and I am always stuck at GRUB not able to detect the usual RAID content.

I've tried running:

```
sudo grub

> root (hd0,0)
```

GRUB complains it couldn't find my hard disk. So I tried:

```
find (hd0,0)
```

And it complains that it couldn't find anything.

So I tried:

```
find /boot/grub/stage1
```

It said "file not found".

Here's the text from the console:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ grub
Probing devices to guess BIOS drives. This may take a long time.

       [ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.   For
         the   first   word,  TAB  lists  possible  command
         completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
         completions of a device/filename. ]
grub> root (hd0,0)
root (hd0,0)

Error 21: Selected disk does not exist
grub> find /boot/grub/stage1
find /boot/grub/stage1

Error 15: File not found
```

**Fortunately, I got one person suggesting that what I've been trying to do is for GRUB Legacy, not GRUB2. So I went to the suggested website, (http://grub.enbug.org/Grub2LiveCdInstallGuide) try to look around, and try:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Unable to seek on /dev/sda
```

This is just the step 2 of the instruction in the http://grub.enbug.org/Grub2LiveCdInstallGuide and I cannot proceed because it cannot seek /dev/sda.

However,

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmraid -r
/dev/sdb: nvidia, "nvidia_acajefec", stripe, ok, 488397166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sda: nvidia, "nvidia_acajefec", stripe, ok, 488397166 sectors, data@ 0
```

So what now? Do you have an idea for how to make fdisk see my RAID array on live cd (Ubuntu 10.10)? Honestly, I am lost, very lost in trying to restore GRUB2 on this software RAID 0 system right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you boot by recovery CD your root devices is not / but the ISO representation in RAM. In this case we have to mount the *real* root partition first.

Check if your software RAID is active:

> $ cat /proc/partitions

You have to expect your `sda`, `sdb`, `dm-0` followed by `dm-1`, `dm-2` and so on representing your partition table entries.

If you do not see the `dm-*` entries you have to activate the software RAID manually:

> $ sudo dmraid-activate

Check `/proc/partitions` again and verify if `grub` is aware of it:

> $ sudo grub-mkdevicemap -m -

The output may differ but should look like (where *ata-WDC_WD5001AALS-00L3B2_WD-WCASY5902194* depends on your hardware configuration):

> (hd0)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD5001AALS-00L3B2_WD-WCASY5902194
>   (hd1)  /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD5001AALS-00L3B2_WD-WCASY5867648
>   (hd2)  /dev/mapper/nvidia_acajefec

Your *real* root partition should be `/dev/mapper/nvidia_acajefec1` right now. We mount this partition for future tests now:

> $ sudo mount /dev/mapper/nvidia_acajefec1 /mnt
>   $ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
>   $ sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
>   $ sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

Check if `grub` is able to map the devices to your partitions:

> $ sudo grub-mkdevicemap -m - | sudo grub-probe --device-map=/proc/self/fd/0 --target=device /mnt

You should see something like `/dev/mapper/nvidia_acajefec1`.

Identify the name of your partition as GRUB device:

> $ sudo grub-mkdevicemap -m - | sudo grub-probe --device-map=/proc/self/fd/0 --target=drive /mnt

The output should be something like `(hd2,msdos1)`.

So far so good. In order to install/update GRUB we are ready to switch to the *real* root partition and update the boot block:

> $ sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
>   $ sudo update-grub
>   Generating grub.cfg ...
>   Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
>   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem
>   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-5-686-bigmem
>   Found Linux on /dev/mapper/nvidia_acajefec1
>   Found Windows on /dev/mapper/nvidia_acajefec3
>   done
>   $ sudo grub-install /dev/mapper/nvidia_acajefec
>   Installation finished. No error reported.
>   $ exit

Your are ready to reboot the system.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've followed all of your step. However, the console shows a little different for the last part for install/update GRUB: **root@ubuntu:/# sudo update-grub**
**sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu**
**Generating grub.cfg ...**
**Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-23-generic**
**Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-23-generic**
**Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic**
**Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-22-generic**
**Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin**
**Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/mapper/nvidia_acajefec2**

Comment: Right now, I have rebooted my system, but it goes to Windows 7 right away, and no GRUB at all. Perhaps I am forgetting something...?

Comment: I've missed the `sudo grub-install /dev/mapper/nvidia_acajefec` in the chroot environment.

Answer (score 0):

The device you need to mount is `/dev/nvidia_acajefec1`, and the device you need to install to is `/dev/nvidia_acajefec`. So roughly following the directions on        http://grub.enbug.org/Grub2LiveCdInstallGuide you would run:

```
sudo mount /dev/nvidia_acajefec1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install /dev/nvidia_acajefec # Note that there is *not* a '1' at the end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried: **ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/nvidia_acajefec1 /mnt**
and I got the following as output: **mount: special device /dev/nvidia_acajefec1 does not exist**